# Convertir Varchar (Datetime en formato MMM DD YYYY HH: SS (AM/PM)) a formato dd/MM/yyyy

Tags: sql-server

Tengo registros en una tabla, en un campo de tipo `varchar` con datos de este estilo: `'Feb  7 2018  2:00PM'` y necesito traer rangos de esas *fechas*. ¿Cómo convierto esta fecha a este estilo de fecha `'dd/MM/yyyy'` para poderlas comparar en la cláusula `where` con tipo de datos que entran de esta última manera: `'07/02/2018'`

Gracias.

Comment: Checa [ask], edita y agrega que llevas al momento

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de dato es la columna de la tabla? Lo ideal es usar tipos de datos de fecha y no cadenas de caracteres.

Comment: ¿Esos datos están almacenados en una tabla? ¿Qué tipo de dato es la columna? ¿Dónde están almacenados los datos contra los que quieres comparar los datos originales?

Comment: Si los datos estan en una tabla, en una columna de tipo varchar, al estar en tipo varchar requiero convertirlos en el where para poder compararlos contra una entrada en formato fecha, algo asi:

SELECT CAMPOFECHAENVARCHAR FROM TABLA WHERE CAMPOFECHAENVARCHAR(MMM DD YYYY HH:MM(AM/PM)) BETWEEN FECHAINICIALENDATE(DD/MM/YYYY) AND FECHAFINALENDATE(DD/MM/YYYY)

Comment: intenta con un CONVERT(DATETIME, CAMPOFECHAENVARCHAR), si no te funciona cambia el lenguaje en tu consulta

Comment: @German, no dejes esos detalles en comentarios, creo que es mejor que edites tu pregunta para que se entienda mejor.

Answer (score 0):

Tomando en cuenta que la cadena de caracteres que contiene la fecha está en un formato aceptado por SQL server, puedes utilizar la función [`convert`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) para *interpretar* la cadena como una fecha. De esta forma tienes acceso a toda la maquinaria de comparación y aritmética de fechas, por ejemplo puedes compararla con otra fecha en el where.

Para convertir la cadena a fecha, pasala a la función de esta manera:

```
convert(datetime, campofechaenvarchar, 100)
```

Donde el último parámetro (`100`) corresponde al *estilo* `mon dd yyyy hh:miAM (or PM)`

Si el lenguaje de tu SQL server no es Español, o tu sistema corre en distintos entornos, asegurate de establecer el idioma de la sesión a Español, de otra forma dará error al no poder interpretar el nombre de los meses.

Para establecer el lenguaje de la sesión a Español, utiliza la sentencia:

```
set language 'spanish';
```

Para escribir esta respuesta, preparé este ejemplo:

```
set language 'spanish';

with
tabla as (
select *
  from (values ('Feb 7 2018 2:00PM')
             , ('Ene 6 2018 3:14PM')
             , ('Mar 1 2018 6:32PM')
       ) q1 (campofechaenvarchar)
)
select campofechaenvarchar, convert(datetime, campofechaenvarchar, 100)
  from tabla 
 where convert(datetime, campofechaenvarchar, 100) <= cast('20180228 14:25:00' as datetime)
 order by convert(datetime, campofechaenvarchar, 100)
```

Que me devuelve el siguiente resultado:

```
Se cambió la configuración de idioma a Español.
campofechaenvarchar 
------------------- -----------------------
Ene 6 2018 3:14PM   2018-01-06 15:14:00.000
Feb 7 2018 2:00PM   2018-02-07 14:00:00.000

(2 rows affected)


Completion time: 2021-02-26T15:22:30.0843055-06:00
```

Comment: Ya cambie el idioma a español y seguí las recomendaciones del convert pero sin embargo ya me cambia el mensaje de error por este:

Error al convertir una cadena de caracteres en fecha y/u hora.

Comment: @German, Asegurate que todas las cadenas almacenadas tengan el formato correcto.

Comment: ¿Ese error te lo da ejecutando mi script de ejemplo o utilizando tus datos?

Comment: Usando mis datos que son:

FechaTransmision Ejemplo: 'Jun 24 2020 12:00AM'

declare @ FECHAINICIAL date = '01/01/2020'
declare @ FECHAFINAL date = '24/06/2020'

SELECT convert(datetime,FechaTransmision,0)
FROM dbo.LOGTRANSACCION

Comment: @German, debe haber una o varias cadenas que no cumplen con el formato, prueba utilizando `try_convert` en lugar de `convert`, las  filas donde no se logre la conversión van a devolver `null`. Los parámetros de la función debieran ser los mismos.

Comment: Continuacion...

WHERE convert(datetime,FechaTransmision,0) between 
@ FECHAINICIAL and @ FECHAFINAL

Comment: Había un error en la respuesta, utiliza el estilo `100` (y no el `0`) al llamar a la función `convert`, ya que la cadena de fecha/hora tiene el año de 4 dígitos.

Comment: Sigo con este error luego de usar el estilo 100
Error al convertir una cadena de caracteres en fecha y/u hora
Las variables del between son en este formato dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: usa convert con el tipo apropiado para esas cadenas también. Generalmente para cadenas que contienen fecha/hora, yo utilizo el formato `'yyyymmdd hh:mm:ss'`, que es reconocido sin importar el idioma del SQL Server. Considera también cambar las cadenas a dicho formato.